# How do I enable CGI execution in the root directory of Apache

Tags: python, apache2, mongodb, cgi

I have built an Ubuntu server and need to execute CGI scripts in the root directory. I keep finding tutorials on how to execute them from cgi-bin but that isn't desired in my situation. I've installed apache2 only (no MySQL or PHP) as I will be using Python and MongoDB. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your virtualhost config use:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
 Options ExecCGI
 AllowOverride None
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
 AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
</Directory>
```